# Is it possible to access ArcGIS's table operations "Summarize..." and "Statistics..." in python?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, statistics

ArcGIS has a few nifty table tools, including Summarize and Statistics. Is there a way to access them through arcpy, or will I have to hack my own methods via math and lists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to be referring to [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000.htm) which :

> Calculates summary statistics for field(s) in a table.

If you are looking for other statistical values not available through the conventional interface, for numeric fields, then you could have a look at:

http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=BDF21676-1422-2418-34E6-A29C6BAC8A0B

A variety of statistical parameters, including several instantiations of skewness and kurtosis, can be derived as well as the ability to obtain frequency distributions for said data.