# Detecting duplicate attribute values in table using ArcPy without Advanced/ArcInfo level license?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, attribute-table, statistics

In ArcMap, the right-click Summarize option very quickly creates a frequency listing of the chosen field:

[image: summarize]

[image]

Note that the count field shows the count of duplicate values. How can I access this using ArcPy?

[Is it possible to access ArcGIS's table operations "Summarize..." and "Statistics..." in python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7421/is-it-possible-to-access-arcgiss-table-operations-summarize-and-statistic) suggests using Summary Statistics, but I can't get any meaningful output from this tool. Instead, it always just lists the total count of features, rather than the frequency of each individual value:

[image]

How can I achieve the result from the second screenshot above, using ArcPy in ArcMap 10.0 with an ArcEditor license (whereby I can't run the FREQUENCY command)?

Dan Patterson's [script](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=BDF21676-1422-2418-34E6-A29C6BAC8A0B) applies to ArcGIS 9.3 so (probably) isn't useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to include a Case Field.  If you do not see this on the tool dialog, be sure to increase its size or use the slider bar on the right hand side to see it.

From [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) help:

"If a Case field is specified, statistics will be calculated separately for each unique attribute value. The Output Table will contain only one record if no Case field is specified. If one is specified, there will be one record for each Case field value."